# Pass array by reference from a certain index on

Tags: java, arrays, reference

In c, you can pass an array by reference from a certain index (say `i`) on simply by passing the address of the `i-th` element.

Now I was wondering if & how I can create a similar structure to work in Java.
I'm currently implementing an inplace radix-4 fft in java for which I'm making a recursive call on only parts of the initial data array.

So say I have a data array `a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, I want to make 4 calls, each receiving a 4th of `a` as a parameter such that I can perform in-place modifications to a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a method that takes an array and start and end index as parameters. This is a pretty common idiom, but of course it expects the method to behave nicely and not read outside of its allowed indices.

It's simple, performant and pretty much the only realistic way in Java. All you have to worry about is buggy methods corrupting the array, but that shouldn't happen right?

Comment: That's the way I've been doing it, I was wondering if there is some nice java-specific way to do it.

Comment: That *is* the Java specific way. You can find plenty of similar examples in the API.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done in Java with a 1-dimensional array directly.

You can do it with a multi-dimensional array.

For example:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
```

Now you can pass `a[i]` to your method, which can modify its elements.

Or you can create a `List` view of the array using `Arrays.asList()`. Then you can use `subList()` to pass parts of that `List` to your method, and modify these parts. These modifications will be reflected in the original array.

For example:

```
public static void changeSubList(List<Integer> list) {
    list.set (0, 150);
}

public static void main (java.lang.String[] args)
{
    Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList (array);
    changeSubList(list.subList (0, 2));
    changeSubList(list.subList (2, 4));
    changeSubList(list.subList (4, 6));
    changeSubList(list.subList (6, 8));
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString (array));
}
```

Output:

```
[150, 2, 150, 4, 150, 6, 150, 8]
```

The only issue is that you can't use an array of primitives.

Comment: I think he wants to directly change the array passed in parameter, which is not possible in Java.

Comment: @Lutzi I also added an alternative that updates the original array (assuming it's not a primitive array).

Comment: Both of your proposed solutions make sense to me but I'd like to keep it simpler & I'd also like to keep using primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that "out of the box.

You could create an" array view" class that only gives access to a specific range.

But you can't create sub arrays without allocating memory and copying entries.